# When attempting to pull POP3 inbox folder using JavaMail I am getting no emails

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

As the title says I am getting no messages using getFolder("INBOX");

It was working yesterday, I do not think I changed anything now when debugging I can see that I am getting no messages.

```
 public String[][] fetchEmails() throws Exception {

        String[][] emailArray;

        Properties props = new Properties();

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");

        store.connect("pop.gmail.com", "******@googlemail.com", "********");

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");

        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        int howmuch = folder.getMessageCount();
        Message message[] = folder.getMessages();//The int = 0, which shows something has gone wrong, message is an empty array.*

        .......

        folder.close(false);
        store.close();

    return emailArray;
}
```

Anything could help, but it has been driving me insane!

Comment: I installed glassfish yesterday, could that cause any conflictions?

Comment: Are you sure that the account's Inbox still contains any messages?

Comment: ended up changing to getting the imap inbox instead, really dont know why it stopped working still

Comment: Just as a reminder: pop3 will only read messages that are new to the pop server.  This is not the same as messages marked as unread in your Gmail inbox.  Pop3 should only ever read a message once.  If anyone encounters a situation like the one above, try sending a new message to the address in question to see if it gets processed.

Answer (score 1):

Once a mail read using pop protocol they downloaded to client and they get deleted in pop server once this below statement 
**store.close()** executes.
So when you run the program again only the new mails are fetched(i.e., those mails which are not fetched previously through any pop client)

see also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol#Overview

Answer (score 0):

I believe that GMail will automatically archive messages retrieved via POP.  You may have to go to the [`Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > POP Download`](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273) page and change your settings.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened again, months later after revisiting this part of the project. Worked one moment.. Then without ANY code change it will not download any mail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd almost say that GMail is having issues: I've experienced this with Gmail and my javamail code. It just periodically either a) fails authentication or b) reports that the inbox is empty.